# How do I make an object move to a certain position after being hit by the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a maze and I want an invisible block to move to a certain position and to turn visible after the player collides with it, however even though I thought I had the right coordinates in my code the object keeps moving to (30,90,8.75) and those aren't the right coordinates I input. Please help. I am a beginner. Many thanks :)

```
MeshRenderer visibility;

void Start()
{
    visibility = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
    visibility.enabled = false;

}
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player" && gameObject.tag == "Invisible")
    {
        movePlayer();
        visibility.enabled = true;
    }
}
void movePlayer()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(19.5f, 45.478f, 11f);
}
```

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP4aT.png)

Comment: Is the object a child of anything? Maybe you have to use `localPosition` and not `position`.

Comment: Oh my god, Daniel thank you so much, I am relatively new to coding so this stumped me for hours earlier. I never would have figured that out alone, that solved it. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the object being a child of another GameObject you have to use `localPosition` and not `position`. See: [Transform.localPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-localPosition.html)

Comment: You never "have to" use localPosition but if it makes your logic easier then you should be using it.